# How to set the target directory in FtpMessageHandler?

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-integration

How can I set the target directory in `FtpMessageHandler`, if not as follows?

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpChannel")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    FtpMessageHandler handler = new FtpMessageHandler(ftpSessionFactory());
    handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpressionString("/my/remote/dir");
    return handler;
}
```

Result:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: Expression [/my/remote/ftp] @0: EL1070E: Problem parsing left operand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting the expression to a literal value, you must include the literal within single quotes.

```
handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpressionString("'/my/remote/dir'");
```

It's an expression so you can dynamically determine the destination directory.